# How do I create a role assignment for a website in an Azure resource manager deployment template?

Tags: authorization, azure-resource-manager

I tried what seemed to be the obvious way with a nested resource:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "testapp",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleassignments",
          "apiVersion": "2015-07-01",
          "name": "<guid>",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'testapp')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "roleDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
            "principalId": "<guid>",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But that didn't work - it create a role assignment, but at the resource group level rather than at the website level. (Is that a bug?)

If I try explicitly specifying a scope:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "testapp",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleassignments",
          "apiVersion": "2015-07-01",
          "name": "<guid>",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'testapp')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "roleDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
            "principalId": "<guid>",
            "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'testapp'))]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That fails, saying that the scope ID must match the URI of the resource.

I also tried some options with a non-nested resource, but none of them would go through either. Is this functionality not supported, or is there some syntax I'm missing that works?

Comment: Could you move the roleassignment resource type out of tthe sites resource type? I'm not sure it'll fix it, but I've seen funky stuff like that in the past. (Keep the dependsOn though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer here: https://www.henrybeen.nl/creating-an-authorization-rule-using-an-arm-template/

*Scope tag is not for individual roleAssignements*. 
The '**name**' tag seems to do the scoping.

```
  "parameters": {

    "roleAssignmentsGuidFunctionsReader": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[newGuid()]"
    },
    "roleAssignmentsGuidFunctionsContributor": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[newGuid()]"
    }
   },
  "variables": {
    "uniqueId": "[substring(uniqueString(resourceGroup().id),9,4)]",
    "functionsName": "[concat('MyfuncApp','Functions',variables('uniqueId') )]",
    "readerRole": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7')]",
    "contributorRole": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]"  
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/providers/roleAssignments",
      "name": "[concat(variables('functionsName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', parameters('roleAssignmentsGuidFunctionsContributor'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('contributorRole')]",
        "principalId": "[ reference( resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionsName') ), '2018-11-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]" //,
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionsName'))]"
      ]
    }
 ]
```